# Ito isometry proof

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

I have been reading Steven Shreve's Stochastic Calculus for Finance II. This question is from Chapter 4 Stochastic Calculus Page 129. This is theorem 4.2.2 (Proof of Ito isometry).

This theorem is about proving the following:

$$\mathbb E I^2(t)=\mathbb E\int_0^t \Delta^2(u)du$$

Here $\Delta(t)$ is an adapted stochastic process meaning that it is $\mathcal{F}(t)$- measurable for each $t \geq 0.$
I can't seem to understand how we got the following:

[image]

Comment: Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to some, such as those who use screen readers. [Scanned pages from books are discouraged on SE network](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/155600/259305). Questions should contain sufficient context so that it is [answerable with the text alone](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1807/290189).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\Delta$ is a simple process and is constant on $[t_j,t_{j+1}),$ i.e $\Delta(t)=\Delta(t_j)$ for all $t \in [t_j,t_{j+1}),$ Thus the integral $\int_{t_j}^{t_{j+1}} \Delta^2(u)du$ is just a Riemann integral and we have $\int_{t_j}^{t_{j+1}} \Delta^2(u)du=\Delta^2(t_j) \int_{t_j}^{t_{j+1}} du =\Delta^2(t_j)(t_{j+1}-t_j).$

Comment: Hi @UBM . I really like the way you answer the questions. You have great exposition skills. Do you mind answering this particular question : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3959231/715112 ? Let me know if I'm bothering you and I won't ask out of turn.

Comment: Don't worry, I am happy to help, I will have a look at that question later.